# Add a row dynamically in between rows to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Initially I have a table as below

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tr_0" class="class_tr_0">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_1" class="class_tr_1">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_2" class="class_tr_2">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_3" class="class_tr_3">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_4" class="class_tr_4">...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table
```

I need to add one row dynamically after tr_0 or tr_1 etc.,

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tr_0" class="class_tr_0">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_0_d">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_1" class="class_tr_1">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_2" class="class_tr_2">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_3" class="class_tr_3">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_4" class="class_tr_4">...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I generated a row like

```
newRow = `<tr id="tr_0_d">...</tr>`
```

I have used the below jQuery style to add a row. But it is not working.

```
$(newRow).insertAfter($('class_tr_0'));
```

Comment: You use class so use dot(`.`) .

Comment: Also you does not need to use `$` in it. Just use `insertAfter('.class_tr_0')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed the dot `(.)` and  you doesnt need to use `$`. Just use `insertAfter('.class_tr_0')`

```js
var newRow = `<tr id="tr_0_d"><td>added</td></tr>`
$(newRow).insertAfter('.class_tr_0');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tr_0" class="class_tr_0">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_1" class="class_tr_1">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_2" class="class_tr_2">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_3" class="class_tr_3">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_4" class="class_tr_4">...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tr_0" class="class_tr_0">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_0_d">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_1" class="class_tr_1">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_2" class="class_tr_2">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_3" class="class_tr_3">...</tr>
        <tr id="tr_4" class="class_tr_4">...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

according to Mohammad's comment

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the dot (`.`) in the selector. You also forgot to close the first *table* in `</table` which fails the code to work for the second *table*.

You also do not need to use *$* to refer the element, simply specify the class as the parameter like `insertAfter('.class_tr_0')`:

```js
var newRow = `<tr id="tr_0_d"><td style="color:red;">added</td></tr>`
$(newRow).insertAfter('.class_tr_0');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
First Table
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tr_0" class="class_tr_0"><td>1 1</td></tr>
        <tr id="tr_1" class="class_tr_1"><td>1 2</td></tr>
        <tr id="tr_2" class="class_tr_2"><td>1 3</td></tr>
        <tr id="tr_3" class="class_tr_3"><td>1 4</td></tr>
        <tr id="tr_4" class="class_tr_4"><td>1 5</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
Second Table
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tr_0" class="class_tr_0"><td>2 1</td></tr>
        <tr id="tr_1" class="class_tr_1"><td>2 2</td></tr>
        <tr id="tr_2" class="class_tr_2"><td>2 3</td></tr>
        <tr id="tr_3" class="class_tr_3"><td>2 4</td></tr>
        <tr id="tr_4" class="class_tr_4"><td>2 5</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```